Is this random walk positive recurrent, null recurrent or trasient

Consider a Markov chain on $\{0,1,2,3,...\}$ with the following transition probabilities. For every $k \in \{0,1,2,3,...\}$:
$$\begin{aligned}
p(k,k+1)& =\frac{1}{2},\quad k\geq0 \\
p(k,k-1)& =\frac{1}{2}e^{-ck^{-\frac{1}{2}}}\quad k>0 \\
p(k,k)& =\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}e^{-ck^{-\frac{1}{2}}}\quad k\geq0 
\end{aligned}$$
where c is a positive integer.
Is this random walk positive recurrent, null recurrent or trasient?

My intuition is that

for small k, there are probability markov chain goes up than goes down.
And for large k, $p(k,k-1)\to \frac{1}{2}$, so the probability of going up and down is half-half, and it is a null recurrent case.

So in all, it seems will fade away from 0 and going to the null recurrent set, and the whole Chain is transient.
But when I tried to compute, it seeems to be recurrent.
If we denote $c_k = e^{-ck^{-\frac{1}{2}}}$, $h(i) = P_i(V_0 < V_{\geq N})$,  where $V_k$ stands for exit time.
then we can write the transition matrix as:
$$\begin{pmatrix}&0&1&2&\ldots\\0&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&0&\ldots\\1&\frac{1}{2}c_{1}&\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}c_{1}&\frac{1}{2}&\ldots\\2&0&\frac{1}{2}c_{2}&\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}c_{2}&\ldots\\\ldots&&&&\end{pmatrix}$$
Then we have $$\begin{cases}h(1)=\frac{1}{2}c_{1}h(0)+\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}c_1\right)h(1) + \frac{1}{2}h(2)\\
h(2)=\frac{1}{2}c_{2}h(1)+\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}c_2\right)h(2) + \frac{1}{2}h(3)\\
h(3)=\frac{1}{2}c_{3}h(2)+\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}c_3\right)h(3) + \frac{1}{2}h(4)\\
\ldots\end{cases}$$.
which implies
$$\begin{cases}h(2)-h(1)=c_{1}[h(1)-h(0)]\\h(3)-h(2)=c_{2}[h(2)-h(1)]\\\cdots\end{cases}$$
Thus, $$h(x)-h(x-1) = \left[h(1)-h(0)\right]\prod_{i=1}^{x-1}c_i.$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^N \left[h(x)-h(x-1)\right] = h(N)-h(0) = 1.$$
$$\left[h(1)-h(0)\right]\sum_{i=1}^N \prod_{i=1}^{x-1}c_i = 1.$$

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Mike yes, I copy from my homework, and I will gradually add my attempt into it, but it takes time, so I just first post the main part.
